# " 肉入" next to an item on a food menu?

Tags: words

Several items on the menu of the restaurant I’m at have 肉入 next to them. I’ve looked this up in a couple dictionaries without success, although I know the general meanings of the separate characters (or thought I did). What does this mean? Meat included?

Comment: I feel l'electeur fully answered the question so I won't add another answer, but I will add that this is similar to the symbols you often see on English menus that say "contains seafood" or "contains meat" for dishes that aren't obviously meat-based. It's a courtesy for those who may not wish to eat meat or may have food allergies.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

「肉入{にくいり}」 （also written as 「肉入{にくい}り」） simply means "***(an amount of) meat contained***".

The phrase is used to describe dishes that contain ***small*** amounts of meat.  It is not used with obvious meat dishes such as steaks, beef stew, etc.

You will keep encountering the phrase:

> 「[Food item] + 入{い}り」

at eateries and grocery stores.

FYI: In case you want to order the dish prepared ***without*** that particular food item, the phrase to use is explained [in this Q&A](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/18015/ordering-food-difference-between-%e3%81%aa%e3%81%97-and-%e6%8a%9c%e3%81%8d/18018#18018).