# What does noun + 抜きにする/される mean?

Tags: expressions

Does it mean "to leave somebody without something/to be left without something"?

「飯抜きにされた分、いつもより余計に食う」

Comment: The general meaning is "without", and who causes the absence of that thing depends on する/される. It'd much easier to give a more accurate and explanatory answer with context and actual sentences. As it stands the question is 文脈抜き.

Comment: I've added the sentence. Can you give me the most literal transliteration you can? It's what I need to understand how Japanese think. Can it be used like ～ずに, sometimes?

Comment: Related, maybe?? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/55671/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18015/9831